# How to enable specific plugins for different languages in vimrc?

Tags: vim

I want to set 3 IDEs in my `.vimrc`.

I've set my Python 3 IDE, but when I open e.g. a .c file some plugins work with this too. The indentation settings are the same as those of python files.

How can I separate the settings to specific language files? Something like this:

```
if (python file)
    Python Settings && Plugins
else if (C file)
    ....
else if (C++ file)
    ....
```

I use vim 7.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `ftplguin` its standard

in your vimrc

```
filetype plugin on
```

then in your `.vim/ftplugin` directory

make files like `c.vim` and `cpp.vim` etc these will be loaded when a specific file is edited. The `c.vim` file is the same syntax as `vimrc`

Using both types of files in the same instance does load both but only 1 settings are kept, SO make sure different files are in different instances of vim

Comment: I find this better than autocommands for filetype-specific stuff. Usually I use autocommands for filetype detection (e.g. based on the file extension).

Comment: It seems to be a clear option. If I import settings for a specific plugin that I want for python but not C++ I should import it in python.vim. Right?

Comment: @exussum Thank you very much! It worked. Someone alse can follow [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_your_vimrc_file_clean) guide. You can include this link in your answer in order to be even more helpful.